# Windows bat file syntax '&' for starting html

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I have a bat file but it is unable to read my syntax & in it.

```
@echo off
start http://localhost/?test=name&pass=pass
pause
```

this works but it kept playing 'http://localhost/?test=name' only... I'm unable to read the syntax &.

Any suggestion? THanks!

Comment: `start http://localhost/?test=name^&pass=pass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the `&` from being evaluated, enclose the URL in quotation marks.  You'll also need an additional set of empty quotation marks as the first argument to `start`, as `start` regards the first quoted argument as a console window title.

```
start "" "http://localhost/?test=name&pass=pass"
```

You could alternatively do as Noodles commented above and escape the `&` with a caret, but the way I demonstrated does not require you to modify your URL query string to make it compatible with your script.

Comment: Just as clarification: What's meant here by "evaluating" is that `&` is normally a special character for CMD, telling it to run a second command afterwards. For example, `echo hello & echo world` would output two lines, `hello` and `world`.